# Why can't I copy the text from a PDF?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, pdf, pdf-reader

I have a pdf that I can't copy text from.

I have tried several pdf readers: Foxit, Sumatra, PDF-XChange, mupdf
NONE of them allows me to simply copy the text!

What could cause this?

Comment: Can you post a link to a small PDF that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: This does depend a *lot* on the PDF file concerned as almost every PDF viewer I have seen has a text select tool and can copy to clipboard but the PDF file itself can request the copy functionality to be disabled.

Comment: This issue may be due to [password protection of the PDF file](http://superuser.com/questions/244918/how-does-a-pdf-prevent-itself-from-being-printed/244942#244942) (that may prevent copying and/or printing) and not affected a particular PDF reader.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, damn... post it as an answer & i accept it. it really did work!

Comment: @Rookie: Unfortunately, this question has been closed, so I can't post an answer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, you could request it to be opened again (click reopen button under the tags). i dont have enough power for doing that yet.

Comment: Question reopened, you can post the answer and even accept it. But please remove it from the question again! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has the solution:

[How does a PDF prevent itself from being printed?](https://superuser.com/questions/244918/how-does-a-pdf-prevent-itself-from-being-printed/244942#244942)

> The print permission is in the pdf file itself and is mostly used by
>   Adobe products. Some products pay it attention, and some others print
>   it anyway.   It is quite easy to remove.
>
> See the article [How To Unlock Adobe PDF Files][1], where it explains
>   how to use [Freeware PDF Unlocker][2] to remove this and other
>   passwords.
>
> **Warning** : Comment by Chris Betti says
>
> > As of Oct 7, 2013, the Freeware PDF Unlocker setup installs unwanted
> >     software without confirmation, and fails to install the product
> >     itself.
>
> Use older versions (if can be found) or search for another product.
>
> [1]: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-unlock-adobe-pdf-files-2/
>   [2]: http://freeware-pdf-unlocker.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 2):

Some PDFs are protected so you can't copy the text. [This link](http://www.ehow.com/how_6065120_prevent-copying-pdf-files.html) shows how to do it in Acrobat.

Another possibility is that your "text" file is actually an image, i.e. it is created from a scan or a screendump. In that case it is still readable, but there is no text in it. If this is the case, a single click on the "text" in Acrobat will shade the whole text in a blue box.

Answer (score 1):

These are protected or restricted document.You can't copy text from it.

You can remove it online

https://smallpdf.com/unlock-pdf

Comment: if the file is stored as images then even if it's unlocked you still can't copy it, unless you use some OCR tool

Answer (score -1):

You can copy text with Foxit, are you sure that the PDF wansn't made from an image?

Yes, you can copy text, I am not allowed to post images but believe me, I've just downloaded and installed FoxitReader 5.3.1.0606, I saved a PPT presentation as PDF, opened it in Foxit, selected text and copied it

[image]

Comment: I can select the text... but i cant copy it, at least not for free.

Comment: Looks like the text was converted to vector graphics, thats why i couldnt copy it. I really thought that every single PDF reader has made the feature only for registered versions, that made more sense than someone converting text into vector graphics!

Comment: Ehh... i dont know what it is anymore. I can search the text by pressing that web-search button on foxit, but i cant copy it inside the program, only from the webpage where the Foxit copies it to.